# C++ How to Sendmessage volume up?

Tags: c++, console, volume, sendmessage

How can I send message volume up? I tried the code bellow but it doesnt work. Please help me. Thank you very much!

```
void main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there are much better ways, but for the quick and dirty solution, I always used `SendInput` with `VK_VOLUME_UP`.

Comment: "WM_APPCOMMAND; Notifies a window that the user generated an application command event, for example, by clicking an application command button using the mouse or typing an application command key on the keyboard." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - seems like this notifies application about those changes, and is not used to cause them.

Comment: If you want more advanced control perhaps you should check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @j_kubik, Interesting. Now why did I never find anything like the IAudioEndpointVolume mentioned in the comment when I was looking for something like that?

Comment: @chris: I used SenMessage successfull in C#, but now I cant work with it in c++. I used this message with Keyboad hook.